# How to get the count of multiple checkboxes which are checked in angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some checkboxes,I need to get the count of all the checkboxes which are checked on click a button,Here is the code below,also I have

### app.component.html

```
 <div class="col-md-3" id="leftNavBar">
      <ul *ngFor="let item of nestedjson">
        <li class="parentNav">{{item.name}}</li>
        <li class="childData">
          <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let child of item.value">{{child}}<span class="pull-right"><input type="checkbox"></span></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
<div><button type="submit">Submit</button></div>
    </div>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  nestedjson = [
    { name: "parent1", value: ["child11", "child12"] },
    { name: "parent2", value: ["child2"] },
    { name: "parent3", value: ["child3"] }
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First bind each checkbox to a value using `[(ngModel)]`. This way we can keep track of 
the values of checkboxes.

Based on your `nestedJson` data, create an object `checkboxes` and populate it with `false` values to keep all checkboxes unchecked at the beginning.

**Component:**

```
checkboxes = {}; 

ngOnInit() {
  this.nestedjson.forEach(item => {
    if (item.value) {
      item.value.forEach(checkbox => {
        this.checkboxes[item.name] = this.checkboxes[item.name] || [];
        this.checkboxes[item.name].push(false);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

In the template, bind each checkbox to its respective value.

**Template:**

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of nestedjson">
  <li class="parentNav">parent1</li>
  <li class="childData">
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let child of item.value; let i = index">
        {{child}}
        <span class="pull-right">
          <input type="checkbox [(ngModel)]="checkboxes[item.name][i]">
        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

To find the count, iterate on `checkboxes` object properties and add to the count by checking if a checkbox is checked or unchecked.

```
findCount() {
  this.count = 0;
  for (let key in this.checkboxes) {
    if (this.checkboxes[key]) {
      this.checkboxes[key].forEach(checkbox => {
        if (checkbox) {
          this.count++;
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**Live demo on StackBlitz:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9rzjy7

Answer (score 0):

How about the following code:

```js
export class AppComponent {
  nestedjson: { value: any[], name: string }[] = [
    { name: "parent1", value: ["child11", "child12"] },
    { name: "parent2", value: ["child2"] },
    { name: "parent3", value: ["child3"] }
  ];
  constructor(){        
    const count = this.nestedjson.map(x => x.value.length).reduce((x, y) => x + y);
  }
}
```